# SSD not mounting in UEFI secure boot off

Tags: linux, boot, ssd, bios, uefi

I have a new Dell XPS15 which came with Windows 10 preinstalled. I completely wiped it and installed Slackware Linux. I can only run Linux in UEFI Secure Boot OFF Mode or Legacy Mode. When I start my laptop in Legacy Mode, the SSD drive gets mounted, but the bios says it cannot recognize my battery charger and refuses to charge the battery. When I run in UEFI Secure Boot OFF, charger is recognized but my SSD(Samsung) does not get mounted - i.e. it does not show as an option in devices to boot from and if I boot SlackWare from USB drive fdisk does not show the SSD drive. My bios version is 01.00.07. Can anyone suggest a fix? If possible, I would like to avoid updating the bios as it is very risky.

Comment: BIOS updates are not usually *very* risky - do you have a reference as to why it would be so on your computer? Also, [Enabling Secure Boot on Slackware](http://docs.slackware.com/howtos:security:enabling_secure_boot).

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer - you need to switch RAID to AHCI for the SATA operation. This way you can boot in UEFI Secure Boot OFF and get the SSD mounted. Check this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2301071&page=2

Comment: Ah, yes, the RAID option for disks always *looks* like it would be a good choice with no downsides. Then you find the downsides.

Comment: Actually any ideas why the bios would not recognize my battery charger and refuse to charge the battery. I need to run in Legacy Mode because UEFI Secure Boot OFF gives me a Hard Drive issue (I don't use the hard drive) and does not wanna start the bootloader.